# How can i specify the user as root inside a docker container

Tags: ansible, packer

I am trying to automate packer commands on gitlab-ci , so basically i am running a docker container ubuntu:latest  and trying to build an image using packer. How can i specify the user as root? or how should i solve this error

please help!

when i try to execute this command

```
packer_log=1 packer build image.json
```

i am getting the below error:

```
amazon-ebs output will be in this color.

1 error(s) occurred:

* user: could not determine current user from environment.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you don't have the `USER` environment variable set. You either need to set it correctly or use the `user` configuration option in the `ansible` provisioner, see [ansible: user](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#user) in the documentation.